# How to fully center a \Shapepar?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, geometry, shapepar

I'm adding a colophon at the end of my document inside a `\shapepar`, however it appears at the top left of the page, and I can't manage to center it, both horizontally and vertically.

I've loaded the geometry options I'm loading for my document, but I removed basically all the preamble and a lot of packages that didn't seem to influence the positioning of the colophon.

Without the `geometry` package, it is *somewhat* centered but it still looks more to the left. Note that I included margins and a `\newgeometry` command to set the same margins for this page only, to simulate what happens in my actual document.

What's the most appropriate way to center it?

### MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=1.5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{shapepar}

    \def\triangledownshape{%
    {0}%
    {0}b{0}\\%
    {0}t{-10}{20}\\%
    %{8.66}t{-5}{10}\\%
    {17.32}e{0}%
    }
    \def\triangledownpar#1{\Shapepar\triangledownshape #1\unskip\ .\par}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{margin=2cm}
\triangledownpar{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut porttitor magna posuere tristique interdum. Maecenas ac nisi rutrum, tincidunt ante a, cursus est. Pellentesque dui ligula, maximus quis viverra sit amet, cursus sed urna. Donec eu erat sed justo cursus tristique non quis nisi. Suspendisse dapibus lorem nec laoreet interdum. Duis sit amet leo sagittis, tincidunt elit in, imperdiet diam. Nulla mi justo, tincidunt a ullamcorper eget, consequat ut odio. Aliquam erat volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean tristique arcu orci, sit amet dignissim ligula elementum vitae. Praesent auctor augue eu lacus tempor maximus. Quisque auctor, odio eu laoreet congue, mi massa facilisis nisi, a faucibus arcu nisi egetet ex}
\end{document}
```

### Current result

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you do not have paragraphs in your parshape:

```
\def\triangledownpar#1{\vspace*{\fill}\noindent%
     \makebox[\linewidth]{%
        \Shapepar\triangledownshape#1\unskip\ .\par}\vfill}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, very elegant! I don't have paragraphs, but what if I had? What would create problems? Just curious.

Comment: @Alenanno: For paragraphs you can't use `\makebox`.

Comment: @Werner I had the feeling it was something like that. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 4):

Box it inside a [`varwdith`](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) environment, which allows you to move it around:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{shapepar,varwidth}

\def\triangledownshape{%
  {0}%
  {0}b{0}\\%
  {0}t{-10}{20}\\%
  %{8.66}t{-5}{10}\\%
  {17.32}e{0}%
}
\def\triangledownpar#1{\Shapepar\triangledownshape #1\unskip\ .\par}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{\fill}

\begin{center}
  \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
    \triangledownpar{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
      elit. Ut porttitor magna posuere tristique interdum. Maecenas ac nisi 
      rutrum, tincidunt ante a, cursus est. Pellentesque dui ligula, maximus 
      quis viverra sit amet, cursus sed urna. Donec eu erat sed justo cursus 
      tristique non quis nisi. Suspendisse dapibus lorem nec laoreet 
      interdum. Duis sit amet leo sagittis, tincidunt elit in, imperdiet 
      diam. Nulla mi justo, tincidunt a ullamcorper eget, consequat ut odio. 
      Aliquam erat volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean tristique arcu 
      orci, sit amet dignissim ligula elementum vitae. Praesent auctor augue 
      eu lacus tempor maximus. Quisque auctor, odio eu laoreet congue, mi 
      massa facilisis nisi, a faucibus arcu nisi egetet ex}
  \end{varwidth}
\end{center}

\vfill

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! :D I chose the other answer, but it's good to see alternatives when possible.