# Wrap a text in a triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, backgrounds, shapes, shapepar

is it possible to wrap a text inside a triangle like the following image?

[image]

Comment: Does the following help? [How to fully center a \Shapepar?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290959)

Comment: Almost yes. But I don't want my text to have a form of a triangle, but rather to be inside a triangle

Comment: just use `\begin{center}...\end{center}` and then line break by hand using `\\ ` with shorter lines at the top.....

Comment: What's  the difference between fitting inside a triangle and forming a (slightly smaller) triangle?

Comment: the difference is that i want triangles' lines also to be shown. The above suggestions imply once i format my text, then to print my document and after that to draw a triangle by hand. I want to avoid such solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is always appreciated if you show a bit of compilable code that shows the effort you already put into finding a solution. If you  have nothing, maybe put at least a bit like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The following might give you some ideas of how you could solve your problem:

**`shapepar` solution:**

As pointed out in the comment `shapepar` might be what you need. Though the question that remains is, what do you consider to be different between the text having the form of a triangle and fitting the text inside a triangle.

What could work is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage[default]{frcursive}
\usepackage{color}
\def\sailshape{%
{0}%
{0}b{0}\\%
{8.66}t{-5}{10}\\%
{17.32}t{-10}{20}\\%
{17.32}e{0}%
}   
\def\sailpar#1{\centering\Shapepar\sailshape#1\unskip}
\begin{document}
\sailpar{\large\bfseries\textcolor{blue}{\\Join Graham as he Sets Sail For the ``7'' Seas} \textcolor{red}{Saturday, September 15th, 2:00 - 3:30 pm, Lake Oconee Reynolds Pantation ~ (012) 345 678}  \textcolor{blue}{Let us know if you can sail-a-brate with us! Reply to Lydia (098) 765 432 1}}
\end{document}
```

Which yields:

[image]

As you can see, the lines break automatically.

**Manual line breaks:**

If you start doing it manually --because you want them to break at particular points-- you should go with David's comments and just break them all manually, inside a `center` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[default]{frcursive}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\large\bfseries\textcolor{blue}{Join\\Graham\\as he\\Sets Sail\\For the ``7'' Seas}\\\textcolor{red}{Saturday, September 15th,\\2:00 - 3:30 p.m.\\Lake Oconee\\Reynolds Pantation ~ (012) 345 678}\\\textcolor{blue}{Let us know if you can sail-a-brate with us!\\Reply to Lydia (098) 765 432 1}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Which gives you

[image]

**EDIT: Solution with a background image**:

You can combine this with any picture of a triangle you might have, or draw one yourself using tikz:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[default]{frcursive}
\usepackage{color}
\def\sailshape{{0}{0}b{0}\\{8.66}t{-5}{10}\\{17.32}t{-10}{20}\\{17.32}e{0}}   
\def\sailpar#1{\centering\Shapepar\sailshape#1\par}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0,anchor=south west] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Unbenannt.png}};
\node[draw=none,align=center,text width=4cm,anchor=south] at (40mm, 58mm) {\sailpar{\small\bfseries\textcolor{blue}{\\Join Graham as he sets sail For the ``7'' seas} \textcolor{red}{Saturday, September 15th, 2:00 - 3:30 pm, Lake Oconee Reynolds Pantation  (012) 345 678}  \textcolor{blue}{Let us know if you can sail-a-brate with us! Reply to Lydia (098) 765 432 1}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which gives you [image]

Comment: Thanks, but this solution solves only partially my problem (the alignment). I want to draw a triangle and then to add the text inside it. So, the remaining problem is how to draw the triangle around the aligned text

Comment: It is not fully clear to me what you want. You can combine the above code with all kinds of `tikz`ery.

Comment: Maybe my edit helps.

Comment: Yes!!!! That was exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 11):

Quick demonstration with TikZ:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[
  draw,
  align=center,
  regular polygon,
  regular polygon sides=3,
  inner sep=-10pt] {
Join \\
Graham \\
as he sets sail\\
\ldots};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple `tabular` and  `3 pstricks nodes`. The text is written first, and a triangle is added around it:

```
\documentclass[x11names]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\psset{unit = 2,dotsize = 2.5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
\rlap{\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\color{RoyalBlue4}}c@{}}
 \pnode[0,6ex]{A}\\  Join \\ \large Graham \\ as he \\ Sets Sail \\  For the "7" Seas \\\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\color{IndianRed2}}c@{}}
Saturday,  September  15 th  \\ 2:00-3:30 p.m. \\ Lake Oconee \\ Reynolds Plantation
\end{tabular}\\[6ex]%
\small%
\pnode[-3.5em,-5ex]{B} Let us know if you can sail a-brate with us\pnode[3.5em, -5ex]{C} \\
\small Reply to Lydia
\end{tabular}%}
\pspolygon[linecolor=white, fillstyle = solid, fillcolor=AntiqueWhite2,opacity =0.2](A)(B)(C)}%
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]