# How to prevent a node exceeding minimum size by making its contents scale-down if they are about to enlarge the node?

Tags: scaling, fit, tikz-node

Is there a way to fit a text inside a node, without resizing the node, rather than fit a node around some text (which, of course, would resize the node)?

Output (first triangle is empty and is exactly the minimum size; second triangle is still the same size as first):

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        % ORIGINAL SIZE (NO CONTENT)
        \path node
            [%
                isosceles triangle,
                shape border rotate=90,
                isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
                inner sep=0mm,
                outer sep=0mm,
                minimum size=20mm,
                draw=green,fill=green!40
            ](T1){};

        % CONTENT FITS (NO EFFECT ON SIZE)
        \path node
            [%
                isosceles triangle,
                shape border rotate=90,
                isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
                inner sep=0mm,
                outer sep=0mm,
                minimum size=20mm,
                draw=green,fill=green!40,text=red,
                right=0mm of T1.right corner,
                anchor=left corner
            ](T2){within};

        % TOO MUCH CONTENT (SIZE AFFECTED)
        \path node
            [%
                isosceles triangle,
                shape border rotate=90,
                isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
                inner sep=0mm,
                outer sep=0mm,
                minimum size=20mm,
                draw=red,fill=red!40,text=red,
                right=0mm of T2.right corner,
                anchor=left corner
            ](T3){OUTSIDE OF MINIMUM SIZE};

        % QUESTION
        \path node
            [%
                align=left,
                below=2mm of T3
            ]
            {How to make contents\\
             of last triangle scale-down\\
             so they don't enlarge the triangle?
            };

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not do the opposite and reduce the text with a scalebox? `\scalebox{.4}{OUTSIDE OF MINIMUM SIZE}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would make a separate command that scales down oversized inputs.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}

\newcommand\MyTextScale[2][20mm]{%
  \sbox0{#2}%
  \ifdim\wd0>#1
  \resizebox{#1}{!}{#2}%
  \else
  #2%
  \fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  MyTriangle/.style={%
    isosceles triangle,
    shape border rotate=90,
    isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
    inner sep=0mm,
    outer sep=0mm,
    minimum size=20mm,
    draw=green,fill=green!40,
    text=red
  }]

  % ORIGINAL SIZE (NO CONTENT)
  \path node[MyTriangle](T1){\MyTextScale{}};

  % CONTENT FITS (NO EFFECT ON SIZE)
  \path node[MyTriangle,
  right=0mm of T1.right corner,
  anchor=left corner
  ](T2){\MyTextScale{within}};

  % TOO MUCH CONTENT (SIZE AFFECTED)
  \path node[MyTriangle,
  fill=red!40,
  right=0mm of T2.right corner,
  anchor=left corner
  ](T3){\MyTextScale{OUTSIDE OF MINIMUM SIZE}};        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Some explanations of the code**

The command `\MyTextScale` is defined with one optional argument and one mandatory, i.e. the maximum width set default to 20mm and the input text. So if you write

```
\MyTextScale[10mm]{OUTSIDE OF MINIMUM SIZE}
```

the text will be of width 10mm instead of the default 20mm.

Then comes the box declaration `\sbox0{#2}`. Boxes are not just fun, they are also a central topic in TeX (and therefore also LaTeX). From start, in TeX, there are 256 boxes named `\box0` to `\box255`. The first 10 are used as temporary boxes by different commands, and it is one of those I have taken. The boxes `\box10` to `\box25` are used for specific stuff by the LaTeX kernel.

In the first attempt I was a bit lazy and used box 0. Instead, I should have declared my own box with

```
\newsavebox\MyBox
```

Then TeX will allocate one of the boxes, or actually the number (register) of one box, to `\MyBox`. By doing so the command would look like this:

```
\newsavebox\MyBox
\newcommand\MyTextScale[2][20mm]{%
  \sbox\MyBox{#2}%
  \ifdim\wd\MyBox>#1
  \resizebox{#1}{!}{#2}%
  \else
  #2%
  \fi}
```

You can get the register that `\MyBox` is allocated to by `\the\MyBox`. If you don't load any packages it should be 26, but here we loaded `tikz` which also allocates some boxes so it will be higher. It can be tested with

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox\MyBox
What is \verb|\MyBox|: \the\MyBox 
\end{document}
```

that should say 26. If you add `\usepackage{tikz}` it will proabably be 38.

The command `\sbox{#2}` stores (and expands) the contents of argument `#2` in the box named `\MyBox`. Then there are (in TeX) commands so you can get the width, height and depth of the box; `\wd\MyBox`, `\ht\MyBox` and `\dp\MyBox`. Again, the the first code I used `0` instead of `\MyBox`. So

```
\sbox\MyBox{Test my box}
\noindent
Width: \the\wd\MyBox\newline
Height: \the\ht\MyBox\newline
Depth: \the\dp\MyBox
```

should give something like

[image]

Now, with `\wd\MyBox` we have the width of the box. Then we want to comare that with the optional argument `#1` and if it is less just print it, otherwise scale down to that specified width. Comparing lengths, or dimensions in TeX naming, is done with `\ifdim`.

Finally, to scale I use `\resizebox` which is defined in the `graphicx` package. Since I have not loaded that package, I guess it is loaded by `tikz`.

One more note. Above I have used the command `\the` to print the box number. This is a TeX command that is used to print out anything that has stored a value. It can be used on box registered, but also e.g. dimensions as for the `\wd` etc commands, and other parameters. For example `\the\baselineskip` prints out the row distance.

Comment: @bp2017 I have tried to give some explanaitions to the code. Please see the updated answer. If it is unclear, let me know and I will try to elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

This approach places the node content in a `tcolorbox`. The `fitting` library is used to fit the text to the size of the `tcolorbox`. The width of the box is fixed using `width=2cm`, which is passed to `tcboxfit`. The `tcolorbox` fitting library has several algorithms for fitting the text in a box. This example used `fit algorithm=hybrid*`.

The MWE compares insertion of 10 words in the node versus inserting 20 words. There are two variants of each. One uses a typical tcolorbox rectangular configuration. The second uses `parshape` to set the text in a triangle consistent with the shape of the node.  These are the results:

[image]

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/310410
\usepackage{shapepar}

\newcommand*{\triangleshape}{%
{0}%
{0}b{0}\\%
{8.66}t{-5}{10}\\%
{17.32}t{-10}{20}\\%
{17.32}e{0}%
}   

\tcbset{tile,              % Hide the tcolorbox frame
    boxsep=0pt,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,left=0mm,right=0mm, % set margins
    valign=top,
    halign=justify,     % ragged right
    colback=red!40,        % blend tcolorbox into node background
    fit algorithm=hybrid*
}
\tikzset{
    inner sep=1mm,
    outer sep=0mm,
    isosceles triangle,
    shape border rotate=90,
    isosceles triangle apex angle=60,    
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path node [%
              draw=red,
              fill=red!40,
              anchor=left corner
            ](T3){\tcboxfit[width=2cm]{\textbf{10 words --} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eleifend.}};
%        
        \path node [%
              draw=red,
              fill=red!40,
              right=0mm of T3.right corner,
              anchor=left corner
            ](T4){\tcboxfit[width=2cm]{\textbf{20 words --} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sit amet ipsum ac purus porttitor tempor. Donec et luctus est.}};
%
        \path node [%
            draw=red,
            fill=red!40,
            right=0mm of T4.right corner,
            anchor=left corner
            ](T5){\tcboxfit[width=2cm]{\shapepar\triangleshape\textbf{10 words --} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eleifend.}};
%            
        \path node [%
            draw=red,
            fill=red!40,
            right=0mm of T5.right corner,
            anchor=left corner
            ](T6){\tcboxfit[width=2cm]{\shapepar\triangleshape{\textbf{20 words --} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sit amet ipsum ac purus porttitor tempor. Donec et luctus est. }}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```